# 2 Simple questions related to xCode and Swift for someone new to Coding

Tags: swift, xcode6

Being new to coding I have a few newbie questions I'm hoping someone could confirm for me.

in xCode is the Playground just for testing code. Whatever I decide to actually be used needs to be copied to somewhere else to actually use it?

ViewController.swift - How do I decide what should go here or when to make a new "file"?

Comment: You may start watching this tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7xUvFs3cPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, playgrounds are for playing with code and experimenting and getting immediate feedback without the usual build and run cycle. However, coding in them is slightly different to normal app programming. One thing you'll notice is that everything is top down, so you have to declare something above where it is used first, which you don't have to do in normal swift apps.

What you should put in ViewController.swift... such a broad question. You might be better off reading an iOS programming beginners book or guide, than asking that here. You should become familiar with MVC for what you put in a view controller. Potentially, you could put everything in ViewController.swift if you desired - but it wouldn't be very nice to work with. The only thing I would put in ViewController.swift, is the code for the ViewController class. I'd create a new file per class I create, new file for a protocol (most of the time), new file for defining constants usually. It's up to you, but at least a new file per class.